# Extracting name and email information from vcard (*.vcf) file

Tags: linux, bash, extract, vcf-vcard

I exported a vcard file (*.vcf) from my google contacts. Now, I would like to extract the information from FN: (full name) and any email address information (EMAIL* or any string with @). I gave ruby, python and bash a shot. The most promising so far was the approach with bash. Here is the script that I have from [Github](https://gist.github.com/songaal/44a1bc66ada65bc3dc08ae6594b45be9#file-vcf2csv-sh), but it is not working properly. I believe it stops when the FN: information is not available which happens to about 50 entries at the end of the vcard file. I still would like the email address info which can be in the Note field or even somewhere else. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

vcard_file=$1

cat $vcard_file | while read line ; do
#echo $line;
if [ "$line" == "BEGIN:VCARD" ]; then
    #echo $line;
    full_name="";
    email="";
fi

if [[ $line = EMAIL* ]]; then
    if [ -z $email ]; then
        email=${line#*:}
        # echo EMAIL : $email;
    fi
fi
if [[ $line = FN:* ]]; then
    full_name=${line#*:}
    # echo FULL_NAME : $full_name;

fi
if [ "$line" == "END:VCARD" ]; then
    # email 이 존재한다면.
    if [ $email ]; then
        echo -e "$full_name\t$email"
    fi
fi
done
```

I call the script via:

```
bash scritpname contacts.vcf > output.txt
```

Here is one vcard entry that is working:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Agathe Strohmeier
N:Strohmeier;Agathe;;;
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:agathe@example.com
TEL;TYPE=CELL:+49123456789
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
TEL;TYPE=CELL:+123456789
NOTE:Anzeigename\: Agathe \nPrimäre E-Mail-Adresse\: agathe.strohmeier@example.com\n
END:VCARD
```

From the following vcard I dont get any information because there is no EMAIL keyword. I still would like to extract the string with @ information and put a "No Fullname" tag somewhere. This vcard entry has no full name or email information but there is a string with the email address I would like to extract:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
NOTE:Anzeigename\: Dennis@uni.de\nPrimäre E-Mail-Adresse\: Otieno@uni.de\n
END:VCARD
```

I am on Linux Mint, so all the command line tools are available. Any google foo was to no avail. I hope I made it clear what I am trying to do. I am also open to other approaches, maybe preproccessing the contacts.vcf file. Thanks for your time & Happy Painting

Answer (score 1):

Could you grep it?

```
grep FN: contacts.vcf
```

(not sure if the syntax is correct)

There are some edge cases where this won't work, but it should work in most situations.